# can we download any file without saving into the application in laravel 5.4?

Tags: file, csv, download, laravel-5.4

I am trying to achieve a task where user just selects a form data and clicks on submit button then data will be pulled from the database after getting the data I want that data has to insert into a csv file and that file has to be downloaded into the user's browser directly without storing that file anywhere into the application. **In laravel is it possible make a download of a csv file directly onto user's browser without storing into the application path?**

My Form is:

```
<form id="statistics" method="post" action="{{ action('MyController@store') }}"">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="option1" name="option1">option1</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="option2" name="option2">option2</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="process" class="btn btn-primary submit">Run Report</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

MyController/store method:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $results = DB::table('table1')
               ->leftjoin('table2 AS s')
               ->get()->toArray();
  $count = count($results);
  if($count > 0)
  {
    $CsvData=array('column1,column2,column3');          
    foreach($results as $value){              
      $CsvData[]=$value->column1.','.$value->column2.', '.$value->column3;
    }
    $filename = 'file_name.csv';
    $file_path=base_path().'/'.$filename; 
    $file = fopen($file_path,"w+");
    foreach ($CsvData as $exp_data){
       fputcsv($file,explode(',',$exp_data));
    }   
    fclose($file);
    $headers = ['Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/csv',
                    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='.$filename,
                    'Content-transfer-encoding: binary\n'];
    return Response::download($file_path, $filename, $headers);
  }
}
```

Comment: Y u use core coding in laravel use this package of laravel:- https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it after creating csv file content echo it with proper headers as content-type:attachment.

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pedidos.csv"');

echo $shtml;

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Please read my question once again as I updated with my code.